# elasticsearch server status 503, discovery fails

Tags: elasticsearch

I am building a cluster of nodes. Two work fine (they are joined into a cluster), I am trying to add a third one (called `eu5`) and while it starts, it does not join the cluster:

```
[root@eu5:/etc/elasticsearch]# curl eu5:9200
{
  "status" : 503,
  "name" : "eu5",
  "cluster_name" : "security",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.4.2",
    "build_hash" : "927caff6f05403e936c20bf4529f144f0c89fd8c",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-12-16T14:11:12Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.2"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

The logs mention a problem with discovery:

```
[2015-01-09 15:35:23,399][INFO ][node                     ] [eu5] starting ...
[2015-01-09 15:35:23,468][INFO ][transport                ] [eu5] bound_address {inet[/10.81.147.186:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/10.81.147.186:9300]}
[2015-01-09 15:35:23,475][INFO ][discovery                ] [eu5] security/FdjfWCWgT-mQtipLdi9BFA
[2015-01-09 15:35:53,476][WARN ][discovery                ] [eu5] waited for 30s and no initial state was set by the discovery
[2015-01-09 15:35:53,493][INFO ][http                     ] [eu5] bound_address {inet[/10.81.147.186:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/10.81.147.186:9200]}
[2015-01-09 15:35:53,494][INFO ][node                     ] [eu5] started
```

The configuration forces unicast

```
cluster.name: security
node.name: eu5
network.host: 10.81.147.186
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast: ["elk.example.com"]
```

and the hint server is available from the one I want to join:

```
[root@eu5:/etc/elasticsearch]# curl elk.example.com:9200
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "eu4",
  "cluster_name" : "security",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.4.2",
    "build_hash" : "927caff6f05403e936c20bf4529f144f0c89fd8c",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-12-16T14:11:12Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.2"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

The 9200 and 9300 ports are available both ways, from the server I want to join

```
[root@eu5:/etc/elasticsearch]# nmap -p9200,9300 elk.example.com
(...)
PORT     STATE SERVICE
9200/tcp open  wap-wsp
9300/tcp open  vrace
```

as well as from the master to that server

```
[root@eu4:/etc/elasticsearch]#  nmap -p9200,9300 eu5.example.com
(...)
PORT     STATE SERVICE
9200/tcp open  wap-wsp
9300/tcp open  vrace
```

Is there anything else I should check?

**UPDATE**: Following [Andrei Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3498062/andrei-stefan)'s comments I switch to `DEBUG` for the logging. I get lines such as

```
[2015-01-12 11:14:41,609][DEBUG][discovery.zen            ] [eu5] filtered ping responses: (filter_client[true], filter_data[false]) {none}
[2015-01-12 11:14:44,615][DEBUG][discovery.zen            ] [eu5] filtered ping responses: (filter_client[true], filter_data[false]) {none}
```

during the discovery phase (the 30 seconds after which there is a timeout). A quick glance at [the code](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/discovery/zen/ZenDiscovery.java#L987) (I do not know Java, though) seems to indicate that the `{none}` means that ping failed.

The tests I did above indicate that, **from the OS perspective**, the connectivity is OK.

**UPDATE 2**: below is the `tcpdump` corresponding to the events above (`eu5`, the machine which wants to join is `10.81.144.186`)

[image]

Full image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLi7r.png

**UPDATE 3**: I filed a [bug report](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/9250).

Comment: Why didn't you put the second node in the list of unicasts? `discovery.zen.ping.unicast: ["elk.example.com"]`

Comment: @AndreiStefan: I am not sure I understand. `eu5` is the server I want to join. `elk.example.com` is my main server, which is used to hint about the cluster to all joined nodes (currently only two: itself and another one). My understanding is that `discovery.zen.ping.unicast` should list one or more nodes so that someone who wants to join can discover the cluster, right?

Comment: @AndreiStefan: as, maybe you mean the second one which joined successfule. I can sure add it, but this should not change the issue (as elk is available)

Comment: Just added it, no change in the problem

Comment: All nodes can be masters? I'm assuming `yes` since `minimum_master_nodes` is 2

Comment: eu5 should have `discovery.zen.ping.unicast: ["elk.example.com","eu4.example.com"]`. eu4 should have `discovery.zen.ping.unicast: ["elk.example.com","eu5.example.com"]`. elk should have `discovery.zen.ping.unicast: ["eu5.example.com","eu4.example.com"]`

Comment: Not to mention that all other settings should be the same for all nodes (except the node name, IP/hostname, ports that are specific to each node).

Comment: @AndreiStefan: I tested that, no changes. The config is the same otherwise. I do not think that the value of `discovery.zen.ping.unicast` is the problem: one master should be enough, this is just a hint to get to a server which holds the info to join.

Comment: Go to the logging configuration file and increase the logging level: `es.logger.level: DEBUG` or even `es.logger.level: TRACE` and see of there are any more clues after this.

Comment: @AndreiStefan: you had a very good idea. I now see during the 3à seconds of discovery `filtered ping responses: (filter_client[true], filter_data[false]) {none}`. I had a look at the code (I do not know Java, though) and it looks like the `{none}` means that the ping failed. Since there is complete connectivity (tcp, udp and icmp) I feel there is a deeper problem. I will update the question.

Comment: Things to double check: 1. the ES version is the same across all the nodes 2. The ports ES uses are, in fact, a range of ports: 9200-9300 and 9300-9400. If you have a firewall in place, make sure the ports range is configured not a specific port.

Comment: ES is the same (including the Java version) and the traffic is completely open between the hosts. I am doing a tcpdump right now to see the actual traffic from the host.

Comment: Maybe you can post somewhere the TRACE log file and your configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an error in the configuration, it should have been

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts
```

`hosts` was missing